# php curl remote login and http PUT

Tags: php, json, curl, put

I created a php curl login for soundcloud but I'm having difficulty finding and coding the PUT data correctly to follow someone.

```
//login      
function login(){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://soundcloud.com/session/'); 
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        $postData='token=&uid=&login_submitted_via=zoom&username=myusername&password=mypassword&remember_me=on';
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cloudcookie.txt');
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $store = curl_exec ($ch);
        return $ch;
    }
```

I've really just been trying everything I can find about PUTs but can't figure out what actual value I'm sending. HttpFox shows "_method=PUT" for POST data, but I don't know how to find what the PUT value actually should be. Any direction would be appreciated.

```
//follow
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://soundcloud.com/followings/cnn');
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cloudcookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://soundcloud.com/people/");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8','Content-Length: 0'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT"); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'$whatvalue');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    $chleadresult = curl_exec($ch);
    $chleadapierr = curl_errno($ch);
    $chleaderrmsg = curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: I believe you meant `"$whatvalue"` by `'$whatvalue'`

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure "what value" should go there.

Comment: But I think you are sure that you dont want to send literal `$whatvalue` instead of the value of `$whatvalue`.